# How to query current and previous quarter data in BIGQUERY

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I am trying to get records of previous quarter and current quarter in BIGQUERY. But not able to figure out how the query will be constructed.

Background: in the 2nd table, it is pulling the historical cost numbers (from XYZ2 table) based on MILESTONE string (which is essentially a string as quarter "2020_Q**1**_M0" (**GOAL** instead basing on the written query under MILESTONE. Can I create a dynamic filter where if the current quarter changes from Q2 to Q3 it updates the numbers with the current quarter (Q3) and also retain the previous quarter which will be Q2)

notes: SA_Date are my date format "2020-05-24"

Current script:

```
-- 1st table pulling the current cost numbers based on current date from XYZ1 table

SELECT CASE WHEN PMD_PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%MAN%' THEN 'MAN' 
    WHEN PC.COUNTRY ='BR' THEN 'Brazil'
    ELSE GEO.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION
    END AS Country  
  , PC.PRODUCT_STATUS AS Product_Status 
  , PC.SA_DATE AS SA_Date 
  , MILESTONE 
FROM
-- PC table
  (SELECT *, CASE WHEN SA_DATE < CURRENT_DATE() THEN 'Legacy' ELSE 'NPI' END PRODUCT_STATUS FROM [xxxx] 
  WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS ='Active') PC

-- Country since PC table has country codes and not description
  JOIN [xxxx] GEO
  ON PC.COUNTRY = GEO.COUNTRY_CODE
-- PCS table joined 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT APC_CODE 
      , COUNTRY 
      , KEY_CUSTOMER 
      , PRODUCT_VARIANT
      , TMC AS PCS_TMC 
      , BMC AS PCS_BMC
      , TMC_TARGET
    FROM [xxxx] 

-- 2nd table pulling the historical cost numbers (from XYZ2 table) based on MILESTONE string (**GOAL** instead basing on my query on MILESTONE string can I want it dynamic where if the current quarter changes from Q2 to Q3 and also retain the previous quarter which will be Q2)
 
    WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS = 'Active'
    **AND MILESTONE LIKE ('previous_qtr_modified') -- filtered to specific qtr**
    AND NOT (PMD_PROGRAM_NAME LIKE '%CANCELED%')
    AND LOCKED IS false
    ) PCS
    ON PC.APC_CODE = PCS.APC_CODE
    AND PCS.COUNTRY = GEO.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION 
    AND PCS.KEY_CUSTOMER = PC.KEY_CUSTOMER
    AND PCS.KEY_CUSTOMER = PC.KEY_CUSTOMER
    AND PC.PRODUCT_VARIANT = PCS.PRODUCT_VARIANT
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT APC_CODE 
      , COUNTRY 
      , KEY_CUSTOMER 
      , PRODUCT_VARIANT
      , TMC AS PCS_TMC1 
      , BMC AS PCS_BMC1
    FROM [xxxx] 
    WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS = 'Active'
    **AND MILESTONE LIKE ('current_qtr_modified') -- filtered to specific qtr**
    AND NOT (PMD_PROGRAM_NAME LIKE '%CANCELED%')
    AND LOCKED IS false
    ) PCS1
    ON PC.APC_CODE = PCS1.APC_CODE
    AND PCS1.COUNTRY = GEO.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION 
    AND PCS1.KEY_CUSTOMER = PC.KEY_CUSTOMER
    AND PCS1.PRODUCT_VARIANT = PC.PRODUCT_VARIANT

    WITH date_var AS (SELECT CURRENT_DATE current_date, EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM 
    CURRENT_DATE) As current_qtr, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) current_year, 
    CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE),'_','Q', EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM 
    CURRENT_DATE),'_','M0') current_qtr_modified, CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
    CURRENT_DATE),'_','Q', EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1,'_','M0') 
    previous_qtr_modified)

    SELECT current_qtr_modified, previous_qtr_modified
    FROM date_var
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding following cte to your current query.

```
WITH
date_var
AS 
(SELECT CURRENT_DATE current_date,EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE) As current_qtr, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) current_year, CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE),'_','Q',EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE),'_','M0') current_qtr_modified,CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE),'_','Q',EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1,'_','M0') previous_qtr_modified
),

-- 1st table pulling the current cost numbers based on current date from XYZ1 table

SELECT CASE WHEN PMD_PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%MAN%' THEN 'MAN' 
    WHEN PC.COUNTRY ='BR' THEN 'Brazil'
    ELSE GEO.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION
    END AS Country  
  , PC.PRODUCT_STATUS AS Product_Status 
  , PC.SA_DATE AS SA_Date 
  , MILESTONE 
FROM
-- PC table
  (SELECT *, CASE WHEN SA_DATE < CURRENT_DATE() THEN 'Legacy' ELSE 'NPI' END PRODUCT_STATUS FROM [xxxx] 
  WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS ='Active') PC

-- Country since PC table has country codes and not description
  JOIN [xxxx] GEO
  ON PC.COUNTRY = GEO.COUNTRY_CODE
-- PCS table joined 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT APC_CODE 
      , COUNTRY 
      , KEY_CUSTOMER 
      , PRODUCT_VARIANT
      , TMC AS PCS_TMC 
      , BMC AS PCS_BMC
      , TMC_TARGET
    FROM [xxxx] 

-- 2nd table pulling the historical cost numbers (from XYZ2 table) based on MILESTONE string (**GOAL** instead basing on my query on MILESTONE string can I want it dynamic where if the current quarter changes from Q2 to Q3 and also retain the previous quarter which will be Q2)
 
    WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS = 'Active'
    **AND MILESTONE LIKE *previous_qtr_modified* -- filtered to specific qtr**
    AND NOT (PMD_PROGRAM_NAME LIKE '%CANCELED%')
    AND LOCKED IS false
    ) PCS
    ON PC.APC_CODE = PCS.APC_CODE
    AND PCS.COUNTRY = GEO.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION 
    AND PCS.KEY_CUSTOMER = PC.KEY_CUSTOMER
    AND PCS.KEY_CUSTOMER = PC.KEY_CUSTOMER
    AND PC.PRODUCT_VARIANT = PCS.PRODUCT_VARIANT
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT APC_CODE 
      , COUNTRY 
      , KEY_CUSTOMER 
      , PRODUCT_VARIANT
      , TMC AS PCS_TMC1 
      , BMC AS PCS_BMC1
    FROM [xxxx] 
    WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS = 'Active'
    **AND MILESTONE LIKE *current_qtr_modified* -- filtered to specific qtr**
    AND NOT (PMD_PROGRAM_NAME LIKE '%CANCELED%')
    AND LOCKED IS false
    ) PCS1
    ON PC.APC_CODE = PCS1.APC_CODE
    AND PCS1.COUNTRY = GEO.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION 
    AND PCS1.KEY_CUSTOMER = PC.KEY_CUSTOMER
    AND PCS1.PRODUCT_VARIANT = PC.PRODUCT_VARIANT
```

OUTPUT:

```
Row  current_qtr_modified   previous_qtr_modified   
1       2020_Q3_M0              2020_Q2_M0
```

The above cte calculates current quarter and previous quarter based on current date and then concatenates year and _Q to match the format that you are using to filter Milestone `**AND MILESTONE LIKE ('2020_Q2_M0')`
Using this cte you can just plug `current_qtr_modified` and `previous_qtr_modified` in the places where you hardcode your current and previous quarter.

Edit: I have updated the query. Refer Italicised text.

Comment: Wellcome! Please upvote if it actually helped you. ;)

Comment: **AND MILESTONE LIKE ('2020_Q2_M0') insert here, instead of ('2020_Q2_M0') use current_qtr_modified.

Comment: Hi Sal, at which line do I insert you script "WITH date_var ........" I'm getting <EOF> currently if i insert it at the end.